# make a dataframe base on the which.max()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a data-set like

```
title <- c('Title.1','Title.2','Title.3')
year.15 <- c( 17,20,11)
year.16 <- c( 19,16,13)
year.17 <- c( 13,12,0)
year.18 <- c( 12,12,0)

df <- data.frame(title, year.15,year.16,year.17,year.18)
df
```

and I want to create a dataset base on the max value in that column, so the expected data frame should look like below

```
year.15  Title.2  20
year.16  Title.1  19
year.17  Title.1  13
year.18  Title.1  12
year.18  Title.1  12
```

many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols=-1) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   filter(value==max(value)) %>%
   arrange(name, title) %>%
   select(name, title, value)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   name [4]
  name    title   value
  <chr>   <fct>   <dbl>
1 year.15 Title.2    20
2 year.16 Title.1    19
3 year.17 Title.1    13
4 year.18 Title.1    12
5 year.18 Title.2    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Obe `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 pivot_longer(-title) %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 top_n(1, wt = value)

  title   name    value
  <fct>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 Title.1 year.16    19
2 Title.1 year.17    13
3 Title.1 year.18    12
4 Title.2 year.15    20
5 Title.2 year.18    12
```